# Crash when building C++ program in Visual Studio with "Use Link Time Code Generation" enabled, only for x64 platform

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, static-linking

I have two C++ Visual Studio (16.5.0 Preview 2.0) projects: a library and an application that uses it. The library project produces four .lib files (for x86/x64 and release/debug), which the other statically links against. The application was until recently working fine in all configurations. Then recently I modified the library and rebuilt the .libs, and now when I build the application for x64 with "Use Link Time Code Generation" enabled, it crashes at runtime with an (apparently impossible) access violation. Note that the x86 build works with or without LTCG, and the x64 build works without it ("No Whole Program Optimization"). I've tried clean builds of both solutions and double-checked that I'm linking against the correct .lib.

This probably isn't a lot to go on, but does anyone have an inkling what the issue could be? Could VS's LTCG somehow cause the linker to use the old code?

Comment: Did You turn the LTCG off, to test if it is the cause?

Comment: Did You try a full "Rebuild"?

Comment: It seems a issue. I suggest you could post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Yes, with LTCG off, there is no crash, and I've tried a full rebuild of both the library and app.

Comment: Is LTCG used for both Debug And Release builds? What is the setting of Configuration Properties -> Linker Optimization -> Refrences?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk LTCG is used for Release builds only but crashes only for x64. References are set to "Yes (/OPT:REF)" for both Release builds and blank for both Debug builds.